# Web3 and MetaMask, receiving event from blockchain

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask

Hey guys I'm terribly stuck with getting events to frontend. I'm using MetaMask. what am I missing?

Solidity event:

```
event enrolled(address payoutAddress, address sender, uint dateOfTransaction);
```

And Web3:

```
MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);
    var depositEventAll = myContractInstance.enrolled({dateOfTransaction: userAddr}, {fromBlock: 4400000, toBlock: 'latest'});
    depositEventAll.watch(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: `{dateOfTransaction: userAddr}` seems suspicious. Are you sure your filter is correct? Did you mean `{address: userAddr}` instead?

Answer (score 3):

There are currently some issues with how MetaMask handles events. It’s always been a hard API to support, because unlike every other method, it’a stateful.

I’m sorry to say that until this internal behavior is stabilized, I need to recommend initializing a second provider if you want to use events, and either point it at a backend you control, or use web3-provider-engine to polyfill the event behavior (metamask is in the process of moving off provider-engine, hence the current instability).